# Unrecognized name when joining 2 tables in Google Big Query

Tags: sql, join, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, left-join

I want to join two tables from different datasets. It is possible to `INNER JOIN` these two datasets but it does not work with a regular `JOIN`.

I want to join a Google Analytics 4 (GA4) item id on the item id of the datawarehouse.
In order to access the GA4 item id I need to `UNNEST` the GA4 items array.

When using the code below, I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized name: dwh_id; Did you mean dwh? at [9:79]
```

Here's the query I'm using now.

```
SELECT
  event_date as ga4_date, 
  ga4_items.item_id AS ga4_id,
  ga4_items.item_name,
  ga4_items.price,
  dwh.Product_SKU__Google_Analytics as dwh_id,
  
FROM `ga4-data` as ga4
JOIN `datawarehouse-data` as dwh ON dwh_id = ga4_id, 
  UNNEST(ga4.items) as ga4_items
```

Let me know if you have the answer :)

Comment: You can't use a column alias **dwh_id** at **ON** clause, so use a base column name **Product_SKU__Google_Analytics** instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, when I use the following code:

```
FROM `ga4-data` as ga4
JOIN `datawarehouse-data` as dwh ON dwh_id = ga4_id, 
  UNNEST(ga4.items) as ga4_items
```

I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized name: ga4_id; Did you mean ga4? at [9:120]
```

Comment: **ga4_id** is also column alias, you can't use it at **ON** clause either.

Comment: Tried that. But then I come to another error that I thought I solved. item_id is nested within an array. Then I get the following:

Cannot access field item_id on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<item_id STRING, item_name STRING, item_brand STRING, ...>> at [9:117]

.

I use the following query: FROM `ga4-data` as ga4
JOIN `datawarehouse-data` as dwh ON Product_SKU__Google_Analytics = items.item_id, 
  UNNEST(ga4.items) as ga4_items

Comment: Would you check my answer? **UNNEST** part should be put before **`datawarehouse-data`**.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Any chance you can write that UNNEST line by any chance? Where should I put it whitout getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. It took a lot of trial and error but I got it:

```
WITH ga as
(
    SELECT  event_date as ga4_date,
            ga4_items.item_id as id,
            ga4_items.item_name,
            ga4_items.price
    FROM    `name-ga4-dataset` as ga4, UNNEST(ga4.items) as ga4_items
),

dwh as 
(
    SELECT Product_SKU__Google_Analytics as dwh_id
    FROM `name-dwh-dataset` as dwh
)

SELECT * FROM ga
JOIN dwh
ON ga.id = dwh_id
```

Answer (score 0):

My best quess of what you're trying to do:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE `ga4-data` AS
SELECT '2022-01-01' AS event_date,
       [STRUCT('item001' AS item_id, 'name1' AS item_name, 100 AS price),
        STRUCT('item002' AS item_id, 'name2' AS item_name, 200 AS price)] AS items
;

CREATE TEMP TABLE `datawarehouse-data` AS
SELECT 'item001' AS Product_SKU__Google_Analytics,
       'col1' AS col1;

SELECT event_date as ga4_date, 
       ga4_items.item_id AS ga4_id,
       ga4_items.item_name,
       ga4_items.price,
       dwh.Product_SKU__Google_Analytics as dwh_id
  FROM `ga4-data` as ga4, UNNEST(ga4.items) as ga4_items
  JOIN `datawarehouse-data` as dwh 
    ON dwh.Product_SKU__Google_Analytics = ga4_items.item_id;
```

Comment: does the `join` statement in general do `full outer join`?

Comment: @Arihant  no. it means **INNER JOIN**.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do I have to write a `STRUCT` statement for each item_id? Because this set I'm using has hunderds of items.

Comment: @JHorizon,  I just reorganize your tables based on your query.  your query is trying to do join 2 tables with join keys. one is a **item_id** in **items** which type is an **array of struct** in GA4 table and another is a product SKU code named **Product_SKU__Google_Analytics** in **datawarehouse-data** table.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much for your help so far!

I can run the script but runs into the following error: Temporary tables may not be qualified at [1:19]

Comment: @JHorizon - can you try running only the `SELECT ..` statement and skip both the `CREATE TEMP TABLE ..` statements. (i.e: line no. 11 onwards)